# Ajax get model property is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have model with this structure

```
public class VariantsByAgeFilterViewModel
{
    public string Variant { get; set; }
    public AgeGroup agegroup1 { get; set; }                 
}

public class AgeGroup
{
    public int? AgeFrom { get; set; }
    public int? AgeTo { get; set; }
}
```

and use ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
        url: $('.chart-container').data('chart-url'),
        type: 'GET',
        data: { chart: $("#chart").val() },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
```

chart-url looks so :

```
@Url.Action(MVC.Reports.VariantByMaleFemaleResult_Chart().AddRouteValues(Model.FilterModel))
```

this is my action

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual JsonResult VariantByAgeGroupResult_Chart(VariantsByAgeFilterViewModel filterModel, VariantByMaleFemaleCharts chart, VariantsByMaleFemaleResultViewModel viewModel) {

    ChartDataModel model = new ChartDataModel();
    var agefrom = filterModel.agegroup1.AgeFrom ;

    return Json(new { data = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

when ajax calls controller action and sets model parameter , agegroup1 property is null, but in model it has value. also simply type property- Variant has value during ajax call.

Comment: post you action please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will work if you refactor your model into a flat one like this

```
public class VariantsByAgeFilterViewModel
{
    public string Variant { get; set; }
    public int? AgeFrom { get; set; }
    public int? AgeTo { get; set; }                
}
```

Internally AddRouteValues uses RouteValueDictionary to parse the object. And as far as I remember it's not good at all at unbinding nested types and arrays.

Hope it helps!